# Read SQL-Server table in pyspark (databricks) with conditions, not the entire table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, etl

Is there any way to read data into pyspark dataframe from sql-server table based on condition, eg read only rows where column 'time_stamp' has current date?

Alternativey, I want to translate :

```
select * from table_name where time_stamp=cast(getdate() as date)
```

into pyspark dataframe.

I am using :

```
remote_table = (spark.read.format("sqlserver")
    .option("host", "host_name")
    .option("user", "use_name")
    .option("password", "password")
    .option("database", "database_name")
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.table_name")
    .load() )
```

which reads entire table 'table_name'. I just need to read rows that satisfy a condition, like 'where' clause in SQL.

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-where-filter/ - use filter, it should be pushed down to source (https://subhamkharwal.medium.com/pyspark-jdbc-predicate-pushdown-817dfc80b72)

Comment: hey, I don't need to filter data after it's loaded in spark, I want to read rows from sql-server that satisfy a condition, which are then loaded into spark.

Comment: You can use a SQL query including a where statement instead of a tablename for the `dbtable` parameter

Comment: "hey, I don't need to filter data after it's loaded in spark, I want to read rows from sql-server that satisfy a condition, which are then loaded into spark." - thats why i included second link to blog post on Medium. When you add filter it will be most likely pushed down to source and will be included in your sql query executed on source database

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateRangeQuery").getOrCreate()

# Define your JDBC connection properties
connection_properties = {
    "user": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=<database>"
}

# Define the date range
t_start = "2023-01-01"
t_end = "2023-12-31"

# Define your SQL query with the date range filter
sql_query = f"(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE t_date BETWEEN '{t_start}' AND '{t_end}') AS custom_query"

# Read the filtered data using the SQL query
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=connection_properties["url"], table=sql_query, properties=connection_properties)

# Show the filtered DataFrame
df.show()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Here, first defined connection info to a sql db and then specified sql a custom query with filtered between two dates and run this as a table. That's all